# Undefined error message when accessing node

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span {
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
}  
span:hover {
  display: fit-content;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span>3.1415</span>
</body>
<script>
  function setBckCol(col) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = col;
  }
  function setSpanListeners() {
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    for(var i = 0; i < spans.length ;i++) {
      spans[i].addEventListener('click', setBckCol('#F9E79F'));                    
    }
 }
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("span");
for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  nodeList[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
setSpanListeners();
</script>
</html>
```

I am getting the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')

spans[i] seems to be th culprit. Where is the error?

Comment: `for(var i = 0 ; i < spans.length ;i++)` don't use less than equal because you are accessing more elements than it has.

Comment: And your script should be placed after the body